# force unbuffered output for the console

Tags: python, command-line

I'm trying to capture blender's console output to a file (as a result of a great suggestions from @Rich Sedman in another post) with something like

$ blender > /tmp/output.txt

The problem is that I need output.txt have **always** the content of the console but blender is buffering this output and not always I can access the text. I tried all kinds of flushing (line sys.stdout.flush(), or sys.stdout = fopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), 'w', 0), etc) and nothing seems to force an unbuffered output.

Is there a way to really force blender to use an **unbuffered** console?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figure out the problem. The python interpreter can be forced to use unbuffered prints if we set the PYTHONUNBUFFERED environment variable. Just use

export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=on

Nevertheless that still did not solved completely my problem because I had a piped  grep together with blender. Hence, although blender was running unbuffered outputs to console, grep was... Just used grep --line-buffered (saw that in s very good post about stdout here https://eklitzke.org/stdout-buffering)

Hope that helps somebody! Thanks for everyone that tried to help!

/edit:
Since 16.01.2020, to make this work you have to launch blender with `--python-use-system-env` to make it work.
Source: https://developer.blender.org/rBS7c2f0074f3fe2411daa7a6e351d7cbc535246871

Comment: Does it work on Windows though? I've tried with SET PYTHONUNBUFFERED=on and powershell $Env:PYTHONUNBUFFERED="on" but still can't get it to print content on live mode, rather than waiting for process end.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know wether it works or not on windows. Probably all the "flush" policies might be quite different from Linux/Mac. Even the grep might flush the output differently, check it out.

Comment: https://developer.blender.org/rBS7c2f0074f3fe2411daa7a6e351d7cbc535246871
TL;DR: it works, but since 16.01.2020 you have to launch blender with --python-use-system-env to make it work.